# Installing report server RDL file to another computer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have developed a report to my development machine with Visual Studio. Looks all are fine in my local machine. But I need to install the same report to dozens of machines. Since I have similar structure in all machines, can I just install it to those machines (like application installation) or do I need to copy the project to all those machines?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to copy the project to the client machines. Are these machines in a network (in the same network)? If yes then you should use Report Server and upload the RDL to the report server. If not, then you need to distribute and install the report with your application installer.

Comment: Those are in different networks having same structure. Do you know if I copy the RDL file where I should copy it? My  Web Service URL is :http://mmlt07022016/ReportServer   and  Report manager URL is  http://mmlt07022016/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

Comment: You need to either use the Report Server UI (http://SERVER/ReportServer) to upload (manually) an RDL or you have to user the Report Server web service to install an RDL from a program or an installer. You can't just place the RDL to a directory.

Comment: You can deploy it (set the project properties to point to various servers, then right click Deploy the project).  Or navigate to the other server /Reports page, go to the folder you want, and click the upload button, and upload the physical RDL file from your project folder on your PC.